# Get value of a string that is passed as parameter

Tags: vb.net, string

I need to pass in parameters to my sub/function.

When the parameter is passed, the value in the string, I would like to get the value evaluated and sent as:

```
Dim strParams As String = drRow(0)

' drRow is a row from DB Table. the value in drRow(0) =  
' "@FromDate=""" & Now.AddDays(-10).ToShortDateString & """&@ToDate=""" & Now.AddDays(-4).ToShortDateString "
```

I would like to see this converted to:

```
Dim strFinal as string 

strFinal = ProcessString(strParams)
```

End Result should be:

```
strFinal = "@FromDate=10/09/2011&@ToDate=10/15/2011"
```

Any ideas how I can do this. I am getting the initial string from DB, I need to convert to the final string, I am not able to figure out how to write the "ProcessString" function.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: What does the parameter look like?

Comment: Are there a fixed number of parameters that you will pass into this function?  And what is this going to be used to do?

Comment: This is a really confusing question.  strParams is the same thing as strFinal.  What are you looking to convert?

Comment: LarsTech is right. The function would only have to return what it was passed...

Comment: @LarsTech Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the question hope that answers. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If I read this right, you have the literal string `@FromDate="" ...`, and you want something to treat the string like VB code, compile and execute it, and return the `strFinal` value that you showed. I'm not saying that this is impossible (it's possible, but somewhat involved), but I would strongly suggest that you come up with a different way to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"IF" you can change your parameter statement to something simple like:

> @FromDate=;-10;@ToDate=;-4

Then you can do something like this:

```
Dim strParams As String = "@FromDate=;-10;@ToDate=;-4"
Dim value As String = String.Empty
Dim parts() As String = strParams.Split(";"c)
If parts.Length = 4 Then
  Dim fromDays As Integer
  Dim toDays As Integer
  If Integer.TryParse(parts(1), fromDays) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(parts(3), toDays) Then
    value = parts(0) + Now.AddDays(fromDays).ToShortDateString + parts(2) + Now.AddDays(toDays).ToShortDateString
  End If
End If

MessageBox.Show("Value = " & value)
```

If it's anything more complicated than that then you will have to start parsing every part of your string with lots of If and Select statements-- you should probably heed Jim Mischel's advice and try a different approach.

Comment: Thanks @LarsTech, this gives me an idea of how to achieve this. I have to use both yours and Jims approach as the string I pass can be dynamic and have more than couple of dates some times. But you guys showed me a way. I will post back once I have worked on this. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is the end result of what i used based on suggestions.. Thanks  Guys.

`Public Function ProcessParameters(ByVal strParams As String) As String`

```
    Dim arrParams() As String
    'strParams = "@FromDate=-10;&@ToDate=-4;&@CompanyID=1"
```

`arrParams = strParams.Split(";")
 Dim arrP() As String`

```
    Dim strFinalParams As String = ""
    For Each strP As String In arrParams
        arrP = strP.Split("=")
        If arrP(0).ToString.EndsWith("Date") Then
            strFinalParams &= arrP(0) & "=" & Now.AddDays(arrP(1)).ToShortDateString
        Else
            strFinalParams &= arrP(0) & "=" & arrP(1)
        End If
    Next
    Return strFinalParams
End Function
```

}